# Infragistics ultragrid client side event for row double click

Tags: asp.net, infragistics, ultrawebgrid

I wanna get client side event for Row double click in Infragistics ultragrid control.

A server side event handler "OnDblClick" is available, but I hope there is some way in client side also.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is our working code for CellClickEvents:

```
<igtbl:UltraWebGrid ID="ultGridScenario">
<DisplayLayout>
<ClientSideEvents DblClickHandler="ultGridScenario_CellDblClick" CellClickHandler="ultGridScenario_CellClickHandler"></ClientSideEvents >   
</DisplayLayout>
</igtbl:UltraWebGrid>
```

added the dblclick handler attribute and value as an example.

```
 function ultGridScenario_CellClickHandler(gridName, CellID, button) {
    if (button == 0) {
        var grid = igtbl_getGridById(ultGridScenario.ClientID);
        var row = igtbl_getRowById(CellID);
        var rowID = row.Id;
        var rowIndex = rowID.substr(rowID.lastIndexOf("_") + 1, rowID.length - rowID.lastIndexOf("_"));
        var cellIndex = CellID.substr(CellID.lastIndexOf("_") + 1, CellID.length - CellID.lastIndexOf("_"));
        if (cellIndex == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            if (rowIndex == 7) {
                ShowScenarioComments(gridName, cellIndex);
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also when I ask VS2010 for intelli-sense for the ClientSideEvents Tag, I get a long list of events.

*Using Infragistics4  10.2.20102.1011*

Some additional Reference:

http://blogs.infragistics.com/forums/p/43398/238276.aspx